# Windows 10 UAC causes ffmpeg to "crash"

Tags: ffmpeg, uac

I'm using ffmpeg to capture my desktop, but when I hit a UAC prompt and after allowing it, `ffmpeg` always terminates

```
[Parsed_ddagrab_0 @ 0000020b627fe680] AcquireNextFrame failed: 887a00260.1kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=0.911x
[Parsed_ddagrab_0 @ 0000020b627fe680] EOF timestamp not reliable
Error while filtering: Generic error in an external library
frame=  190 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=     187kB time=00:00:06.20 bitrate= 246.9kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=0.973x
video:184kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.690141%
```

This is the ffmpeg command, any ideas to prevent the self-termiation? I did try running `ffmpeg` in adminstrator mode, no help.

```
ffmpeg -y ^
    -init_hw_device d3d11va -filter_complex "ddagrab=video_size=1280x720:offset_x=1000:offset_y=300" -c:v h264_nvenc -qp 0 ^
    vid.mp4
```

Comment: Temporary workaround - see if turning UAC off temporarily changes anything.   https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-turn-off-User-Account-Control-in-Windows.html

Comment: so that is kinda by-design. UAC is implemented so that no program running in the users session is allowed to interact with the UAC session (its literally a different user session) to prevent malware from just "pressing 'y' " to allow admin access. Even MS office apps like Teams have this problem. when ever you are sharing your screen, and the UAC auth screen comes up, not only is that screen not visible to the meeting members, the presenting screen just freezes and won't resume unless the presenter stops sharing and restarts it. I think there may be a UAC setting you can disable to address it/

Comment: try disabling this setting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-switch-to-the-secure-desktop-when-prompting-for-elevation . it does reduce the protection that UAC provides however.

Comment: I mean, this is not so much that ffmpeg cannot capture the screen, but more, can ffmpeg continue after UAC has been passed instead of terminating? Teminating breaks my video...

Comment: @bilogic - You have confirmed this issue exists with the current version of ffmpeg?

Comment: no, but it is not that distant that UAC did not exists, `ffmpeg version 2023-01-04-git-4a80db5fc2-full_build-www.gyan.dev`